# Is the following explanation of `prototypes` in Javascript valid?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

I have been trying to learn about prototypes since I needed quite a bit of clarity on them. I have been using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) MDN article and its related articles for reference.

After some reading, I got a bit of clarity on prototypes and tried putting them in my own words and would like to know if it is right and would *love* to know if and where I am wrong

START OF EXPLANATION

Every object is created using a constructor function of some sort. Say, we create an object as follows.

```
let obj = new Object();
```

Here, `Object` is the constructor function. The thing about functions is that, all of them (including non-constructor functions) have a property called `prototype` on them. This `prototype` property defines what will be the prototype of *any* object that is created using the `new` keyword and said constructor function. You can check the prototype property as follows:

```
console.log(Object.prototype);
```

The above piece of code will return an object with a bunch of methods that any object created using `new Object()` can use.

In the above example, if the wording is too confusing, you can replace all occurrences of `Object` with *any* other constructor function such as `Array`, `Date` or even custom constructor functions such as `Person` or something else that you may have defined.

END OF EXPLANATION

Is my understanding right? If not, can you point me where I went wrong?

Comment: This question is perfectly clear, it doesn't need more focus.

Comment: "Every object is created using a constructor function of some sort" is very obviously not true.

Comment: *"Is my understanding right? If not, can you point me where I went wrong?"* In big picture terms, yes, your understanding is mostly correct (but incomplete). There are some specifics that are incorrect. *"Every object is created using a constructor function of some sort. Say, we create an object as follows."* That's not quite correct, JavaScript also has literal forms (`{}` [object], `[]` [array], and `//` [regular expression]) that create objects without using a constructor function. Those forms assign `Object.prototype`, `Array.prototype`, and `RegExp.prototype` to the objects *(cont'd)*

Comment: @RobinZigmond can you tell me how it is not true? Is there any object creation mechanism other than literals and `Object.create` that does not use constructors

Comment: *(continuing)* they create, even though the constructor itself isn't invoked. *"The thing about functions is that, all of them (including non-constructor functions) have a property called `prototype` on them."* That's incorrect, arrow functions and class methods do not have a `prototype` property.

Comment: Objects have an internal `[[Prototype]]` property that references the public *prototype* of their constructor, that's where they inherit properties from. The *Object* constructor is a function (as are all constructors), its internal `[[Prototype]]` references *Function.protoptype*, which in turn inherits from *Object.prototype*, which is where the chain ends. The *Object.prototype* object's `[[Prototype]]` is *null*. :-)

Comment: Separate from the above, note that you've focussed on using constructor functions, but that's not the only way objects get prototypes. You can also create objects using `Object.create` and specify the prototype directly: `const x = Object.create(y);` creates an object that uses `y` as its prototype. (You can also use `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but...don't... :-) )

Comment: And then there's the whole question of: Yes, but...why? What are prototypes for? What do they do? E.g., you need to explain property lookup and such.

Comment: @BlackWind @TJCrowder has already explained this before I could get to it. In practice I very rarely use the `new` keyword - in my opinion fewer people would get confused if Javascript didn't use things like this to pretend to be a "standard OO" language like Java/C#, when it is very much not (and in my opinion much the better for it, but that's a whole other debate!)

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the explanation about the internal `[[Prototype]]`. I do have a follow-up about the `Object` constructor function's `[[Prototype]]`. I can see why its prototype (immediate in the chain) should be `Function.prototype`. However, I just tried `console.log(Object.prototype)` and it isn't the same as `Function.prototype`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—sure, literals are created without directly calling the related constructor, but the result is the same as if they were. Similarly for arrow functions in terms of inheritance: they have a `[[Prototype]]` property that references *Function.prototype*, however there are other details that are different. I voted to close because I think it takes a long and considered article to properly explain ECMAScript inheritance plus good/bad explanations are very subjective, but open and answer fully if you wish. :-)

Comment: @RobG - My point about arrow functions and class methods is about the `prototype` property, not the `[[Prototype]]` internal field. It was correcting the OP's statement that "all functions have a `prototype` property."

Comment: @BlackWind—yes. Try `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype`, which shows Object inherits from Function.prototype. Then `Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype` which shows that Function inherits from Object.prototype. Finally `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === null` shows the end of the chain, which is `Object -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null` where `->` means "inherits from". I hope that helps!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—fair enough. :-)

Comment: @RobG I see where I went wrong. Thanks for the explanation. `Object.prototype` is NOT the prototype of the `Object` constructor function itself. It is the prototype of any object created *using* `Object` as a constructor function. The constructor function `Object` would have its own prototype which happens to be `Function.prototype`.

Comment: @BlackWind - Correct. :-) (I actually thought you already understood that, from the explanation in the question.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This question has been reopened. Please compose your comments as an answer.

Comment: Literals have been mentioned already, but also note that, if you redefine, say, `Array`, then `[]` will still be an original Array in recent ES editions (before those, redefining `Array` could be used to steal JSON data), however, `new Array` will be an instance of your redefined constructor. _“[All functions] have a property called `prototype` on them.”_ — No! Other than the obvious exceptions, arrow functions and methods, `Proxy` is a constructor, but has no such property. It’s an outlier in that a Proxy instance gets the prototype from its target (first argument) upon construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my understanding right? If not, can you point me where I went wrong?

In big picture terms, yes, your understanding is mostly correct, but the explanation is incomplete, and there are some specifics that are incorrect.

> Every object is created using a constructor function of some sort.

That's not quite correct, JavaScript also has literal forms (`{}` [object], `[]` [array], and `//` [regular expression]) that create objects without using a constructor function. Those forms assign `Object.prototype`, `Array.prototype`, and `RegExp.prototype` (respectively) to the objects they create, even though the constructor itself isn't invoked.

There are also other ways of creating objects that don't go through constructor functions at all. For instance, there's `Object.create`, which creates an object and assigns the prototype you supply to it:

```js
const p = {};
const obj = Object.create(p);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === p); // true
```

(There are also more obscure ways of creating objects through implicit conversion.) You can also change the prototype of an existing object by using `Object.setPrototypeOf`.

> The thing about functions is that, all of them (including non-constructor functions) have a property called `prototype` on them.

Not quite, arrow functions and class methods do not have a `prototype` property and cannot be used as constructors:

```js
const arrow = () => {};
class X {
    method() {
    }
    static staticMethod() {
    }
}
console.log("prototype" in arrow);              // false
console.log("prototype" in X.prototype.method); // false
console.log("prototype" in X.staticMethod);     // false
```

> This `prototype` property defines what will be the prototype of any object that is created using the `new` keyword and said constructor function.

Correct. (Constructor functions can mess with what they return, but that's the usual, standard behavior.)

At this point in an explanation I'd probably point out the distinction between the `prototype` property on functions and the prototype of an object. Beginners sometimes think setting a `prototype` property on an object will change its prototype; it doesn't, that name is only significant on functions, and it's **not** the function's prototype, it's just a property that (as you said) will be used to assign the prototype of an object created using `new` with that function. The prototype of an object is held in an internal field of the object called `[[Prototype]]`. That field isn't *directly* accessible, but you can access it via `Object.getPrototypeOf` and change it via `Object.setPrototypeOf` (you can also use the deprecated `__proto__` accessor property, which is just a wrapper around those functions — but don't use `__proto__`, use the functions directly).

But aside from all that, there's a big unanswered question in your explanation: What are prototypes *for*? What do they do? Why have them?

The answer is that they provide JavaScript's inheritance mechanism. When you get the value of a property on an object and the object doesn't have a property of its own with the given key, the JavaScript engine looks at the object's prototype to see if it has the property (and the prototype of the prototype, and so on through the chain):

```js
const parent = {
    a: "a property on base",
};
const child = Object.create(parent);
child.b = "a property on child";
const grandChild = Object.create(child);
grandChild.c = "a property on grandChild";

console.log(grandChild.a); // "a property on base"
console.log(grandChild.b); // "a property on child"
console.log(grandChild.c); // "a property on grandChild"

const hasOwn =
    Object.hasOwn || // Fairly new, ES2022
    Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);

console.log(`hasOwn(grandChild, "a")? ${hasOwn(grandChild, "a")}`); // false
console.log(`hasOwn(grandChild, "b")? ${hasOwn(grandChild, "b")}`); // false
console.log(`hasOwn(grandChild, "c")? ${hasOwn(grandChild, "c")}`); // true
```

Those example property values are strings, but this is widely used where the property values are functions, providing a means of inheriting methods from parent objects.

The property access process is *asymmetrical*, though; it only works as described above for *getting* a property's value. If you *set* a property's value on an object, it always sets it on the object itself, not on its prototype:

```js
const parent = {
    prop: "parent",
};
const child = Object.create(parent);

const hasOwn =
    Object.hasOwn || // Fairly new, ES2022
    Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);

console.log(`[Before] child.prop: ${child.prop}`);
// => "[Before] child.prop: parent"
console.log(`[Before] hasOwn(child, "prop")? ${hasOwn(child, "prop")}`);
// => "[Before] hasOwn(child, "prop")? false"

child.prop = "child";

console.log(`[After]  child.prop: ${child.prop}`);
// => "child.prop: child"
console.log(`[After]  hasOwn(child, "prop")? ${hasOwn(child, "prop")}`);
// => "[After]  hasOwn(child, "prop")? true"
```

(This difference between getting and setting the property value applies to data properties [the kind we mostly create]; accessor properties work differently because getting and setting the property result in function calls, and the accessor's setter function can do whatever the author wants it to do.)

Comment: I tried to follow the object creation to its roots into the internal methods. One of the most common methods is [OrdinaryObjectCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryobjectcreate), which takes the prototype as an argument. In case of object literals, it's not clear, where the prototype value comes from. Similarly the prototype is passed to the internal methods creating built-in objects. Is the value of `proto` argument created at interpret/compile time?

Comment: @Teemu - I'm not sure I'm reading that question correctly, but: When the JavaScript engine creates a new [realm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-code-realms) (global environment and the things in it), it creates the fundamental functions and other objects, including the object that becomes the initial (and hopefully only) value of `Object.prototype`, which the spec calls [`%Object.prototype%`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object). *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* That object is used as the `proto` argument to `OrdinaryCreateObject` when [evaluating an object initializer](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Similarly, with `[]`, [`%Array.prototype%`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) is used, although not with `OrdinaryCreateObject` ([details](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-array-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation)).

Comment: (Ignore the "and hopefully only" in my first comment above. `Object.prototype` is neither writable nor configurable, so its value can't be changed. I did check that before posting the comment, but then forgot to remove that part! :-) )

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I was confused, because %prototype% is not on the list of [[Intrinsicts]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#table-well-known-intrinsic-objects), but of course it isn't, as it's %Object.prototype%, and %Object%  is on the list.

Comment: @Teemu - Yeah. It used to be `%ObjectPrototype%` and [had its own entry on that list](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-well-known-intrinsic-objects), but they changed it for some reason.